# How to get the height constraint declared by snapkit for UIView?

Tags: swift, snapkit

For example, I declare some constraints through snapkit for a UIView:

```swift
timeProgress.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
  make.left.equalTo(startTime.snp_right).offset(15)
  make.right.equalTo(endTime.snp_left).offset(-15)
  make.height.equalTo(5)
  make.centerY.equalTo(startTime)
}
```

How can I get the height constraint for the timeProgress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep a global reference to the constraint.

```
let timeProgressHeightConstant = 5.0

timeProgress.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.left.equalTo(startTime.snp_right).offset(15)
    make.right.equalTo(endTime.snp_left).offset(-15)
    make.height.equalTo(timeProgressHeightConstant)
    make.centerY.equalTo(startTime)
}
```

Hence, you could now access `self.timeProgressHeightConstant`.

Comment: Thanks！But i also want know how can I get the width constraint for it?

Comment: @tongxing There is no shortcut to get the width constraint in this case. You need to calculate yourself manually.

Answer (score 4):

You can hold a reference to the height constraint:

```
var timeHeightConstraint: Constraint

timeProgress.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.left.equalTo(startTime.snp_right).offset(15)
    make.right.equalTo(endTime.snp_left).offset(-15)
    self.timeHeightConstraint = make.height.equalTo(5).constraint
    make.centerY.equalTo(startTime)
}
```